# Como retirar linhas de arquivo CSV usando PHP?

Tags: php, csv

Eu preciso retirar as duas primeiras linhas de um arquivo CSV, tem alguma função para isso em PHP?

Comment: tentou usar o [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)?

Comment: Sua pergunta é, se existe uma função nativa!?

Comment: `fputcsv` e `fgetcsv` (tanto as funções como os métodos de `SplFileObject` ) são boas maneiras de trabalhar com CSV no PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu gosto de usar a função `SplFileObject`do PHP. Você pode abrir o arquivo e apontar para a linha a partir da qual deseja ler o arquivo através da função `seek`.

Exemplo `relatorio.csv`:

```
a1,b1,c1
a2,b2,c2
a3,b3,c3
a4,b4,c4
a5,b5,c5
```

O código ficaria assim:

```
$file = new \SplFileObject('relatorio.csv', 'r');

// Coloca o ponteiro na segunda linha do arquivo
$file->seek(1);

// continue o laço até que seja o fim da linha
while ($file->eof() === false) {
    // obtém o dado de uma linha do CSV
    var_dump($file->fgetcsv());
}
```

O resultado seria esse:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "a3"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "b3"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "c3"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "a4"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "b4"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "c4"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "a5"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "b5"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "c5"
}
```

Observação: O `fseek` coloca a leitura do arquivo a partir da linha informada. O PHP conta as linhas do arquivo a partir do `0`.

Você também pode usar a função `array_slice` combinado com `file` para obter todas as linhas do arquivo no `array`. O `file` abre cada linha num `array`, e o `array_slice` "corta" o `array` com o valor indicado.

Veja:

```
 var_dump(array_slice(file('relatorio.csv'), 2));
```

**Observação**: Só use o segundo exemplo se o tamanho do CSV for pequeno, pois dependendo da quantidade de linha, poderá sobrecargar a memória, pois `file` lê cada linha para um `array`.

A primeira solução lê linha por linha, economizando processamento/memória.

Comment: Sensacional, solução em uma linha de quem entende de verdade da linguagem. PS: se puder adicione uma breve explicação sobre `array_slice`. O +1 já esta garantido

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: É o segundo downvote sem explicação que recebo [e geralmente eu não faço isso, costumo sempre comentar os meus votos negativos]. Quem fez isso poderia ao menos deixar um comentário para poder ajudar as pessoas, que querem ajudar a comunidade a crescer, a entender o motivo dos negativos, para saber o que pode ser melhorado.

Answer (score -2):

É possível fazer isso em PHP apesar de não ser uma única função como você perguntou:

```
// Leia o arquivo
$arquivo = fopen('seu_arquivo.csv', 'r');

// Pega todas as linhas do arquivo
while (($linha = fgetcsv($arquivo)) !== FALSE) {
  // Armazena as linhas em um array de dados
  $dados[] = $linha;
}
fclose($arquivo);

// Remove o primeiro elemento do array (ou seja, a primeira linha do arquivo que foi salva)
array_shift($dados);

// Faz novamente para removera segunda
array_shift($dados);

// Abre arquivo para escrita
$arquivo = fopen('seu_arquivo.csv', 'w');

// Escreve no arquivo as linhas salvas no array
foreach ($dados as $dado) {
    fputcsv($arquivo, $dado);
}
fclose($arquivo);
```

Caso você só queira os dados e não quer sobre-escrever o arquivo, só ignore as  últimas 7 linhas de código e utilize o array `$dados`.

Comment: Jovem, pessoalmente, achei que seu código dá muita volta para fazer uma coisa simples e gastando mais memória do que deveria.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters entendi sua opinião. A diferença real entre meu código e o seu é que ao não usar o `seek()` uso 2 comandos de `array_shift()` a mais que você e uso `foreach` ao invés de `while`. Agora se isso é muita volta pra você. Tudo bem :) Obrigado pelo feedback.

Comment: Na verdade, você salva todas as linhas do CSV para um outro `array`. Se o CSV do cara tivesse 30.000 linhas, você teria muita coisa na memória, podendo causar um fatal error. Eu tô falando sério. Da maneira que eu fiz, você lê uma linha do arquivo por vez, sem "abusar" da memória.

Comment: Eu poderia fazer de maneira bem rápida (parecida com sua solução) usando apenas uma linha... `var_dump(array_slice(file('arquivo.csv'), 1));`, mas não fiz pensando na memória

Comment: Hmm, agora entendi seu ponto @WallaceMaxters obrigado, vou verificar uma forma de melhorar e modificar a resposta.